# Proper use of option_page_capability_{$page_name}

Tags: options, capabilities

I am having trouble giving access to an options page to Editors.  I am pretty sure I need to use the filter `option_page_capability_{$page_name}` but it is not working for me. Is there a specific place to hook this? I am still getting the `Cheatin', uh?` error with this:

```
    function bf_ins_capability(){
        return 'edit_posts';
    }

    add_filter( 'option_page_capability_brightfire-insurance-settings', 'bf_ins_capability' );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So in this hook is not exactly looking for the `{$page_name}`. Once I replaced the `{$page_name}` part of this filter to the `{$option_group}` parameter from my `register_settings()` function, all is well in the land of WordPress. Here is what my update needed to look like.

```
function bf_ins_capability(){
  return 'edit_posts';
}

add_filter( 'option_page_capability_bf_insurance_settings', 'bf_ins_capability');
```

Comment: Thanks! I referenced your answer on my comment on wp codex for this filter.